# How to disable automatic scrolling of slides within fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js with sections and slides - all I want to accomplish is to remove the automatic slide scrolling. I have tried to find the correct option to do this in their documentation (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js) but was unfortunately not able to find it.

Currently I am using this code to initialize it:

```
    new fullpage('#fullpage', {
        autoScrolling:true,
        scrollHorizontally: true,
        slidesNavigation: true,
        loopHorizontal: false, 
        lazyLoading: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 700,
        navigation: true,
        easingcss3: 'ease',
        loopBottom: true,
        responsiveWidth: 1000,
        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                fullpage_api.moveSlideRight();
            }, 15000);
        }
    });
```

setting the option autoScrolling:false removes the entire scroll effect, but I would only like to stop the auto scroll on the slides not on the sections.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was absolutely blind here of course this was the issue here:

```
 afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                fullpage_api.moveSlideRight();
            }, 15000);
 }
```

not sure why this was in there, probably copied it from somewhere - removed this now and working as expected.